# in linux char device driver, what does the poll_queue_proc function do?

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, polling, device-driver

There is a concept of synchronous polling for multiple device files in linux and I'm trying to understand how it works.
in linux 2.6.23 source drivers/char/random.c, I see following code

```
static DECLARE_WAIT_QUEUE_HEAD(random_read_wait);
static DECLARE_WAIT_QUEUE_HEAD(random_write_wait);

static unsigned int
random_poll(struct file *file, poll_table * wait)
{
    unsigned int mask;

    poll_wait(file, &random_read_wait, wait);
    poll_wait(file, &random_write_wait, wait);
    mask = 0;
    if (input_pool.entropy_count >= random_read_wakeup_thresh)
        mask |= POLLIN | POLLRDNORM;
    if (input_pool.entropy_count < random_write_wakeup_thresh)
        mask |= POLLOUT | POLLWRNORM;
    return mask;
}
```

the poll_table is defined as below in include/linux/poll.h

```
typedef void (*poll_queue_proc)(struct file *, wait_queue_head_t *, struct poll_table_struct *);

typedef struct poll_table_struct {
    poll_queue_proc qproc;
} poll_table;
```

I saw in a book (Ch.5, Essential Linux Device Drivers, Venkateswaran) that "The poll_table is a table of wait queues owned by device drivers that are being polled for data." but the source says it is just a function pointer. and I can't find what this function qproc is doing.
Below is the function poll_wait defined in include/linux/poll.h.

```
static inline void poll_wait(struct file * filp, wait_queue_head_t * wait_address, poll_table *p)
{
    if (p && wait_address)
        p->qproc(filp, wait_address, p);
}
```

and in the book it says(about an example char driver for a mouse), "mouse_poll() uses the library function, poll_wait(), to add a wait queue (mouse_wait) to the kernel poll_table and go to sleep." so poll_wait can sleep, but in the random_poll() function above, we see tow consecutive poll_wait functions. so does the random_poll polls for read and write availability sequentially and sends the mask to the application? I would appreciate if someone can show me the example of poll_queue_proc function. I couldn't find it in the linux driver source(should it appear only in application?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`drivers/char/random.c:random_poll()` is called when userspace calls
`select()` (or `poll()` or `epoll_wait()` for that matter) with a file
descriptor referring to `/dev/random`.

These system calls are at the basis of *event multiplexing*. In the
following program, userspace opens a number of input sources (say
`/dev/random` and `/dev/ttyS4`) and calls `select()` *on both of
them* to block until *any of them* has input data to be read. (There
are other event sources than input, input is just the simplest.)

```
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


#define _SYSE(ret, msg) do {                    \
    if (ret == -1) {                            \
        perror(msg);                            \
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                     \
    }                                           \
} while (0)

static int /*bool: EOF detected*/ consume_fd(int fd, const char* msg)
{
    char tmp[64];
    ssize_t nread;

    nread = read(fd, tmp, sizeof(tmp));
    _SYSE(nread, "read");
    if (nread == 0 /*EOF*/)
        return 1;

    printf("%s: consumed %ld bytes\n", msg, nread);
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    int random_fd, tty_fd, nfds = 0;

    random_fd = open("/dev/random", O_RDONLY);
    _SYSE(random_fd, "open random");
    if (random_fd > nfds)
        nfds = random_fd+1;

    tty_fd = open("/dev/ttyS4", O_RDONLY);
    _SYSE(tty_fd, "open tty");
    if (tty_fd > nfds)
        nfds = tty_fd+1;

    while (1) {
        fd_set in_fds;
        int ret;

        FD_ZERO(&in_fds);
        FD_SET(random_fd, &in_fds);
        FD_SET(tty_fd, &in_fds);

        ret = select(nfds, &in_fds, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        _SYSE(ret, "select");

        if (FD_ISSET(random_fd, &in_fds)) {
            int eof_detected = consume_fd(random_fd, "random");
            if (eof_detected) 
                break;
        }
        if (FD_ISSET(tty_fd, &in_fds)) {
            int eof_detected = consume_fd(tty_fd, "tty");
            if (eof_detected) 
                break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output will appear once either random numbers are available, or the
serial line has data. (Note that nowadays `/dev/random` does not
block, but rather generates pseudo random numbers, so output is really
fast.)

It is when the `select()` call enters the kernel that `random_poll()`
is called, and another, comparable, function somewhere in the TTY
layer - simply because `select()` passes those file descriptors as
parameters. Those functions are supposed to simply enqueue the caller
into a `poll_table` that is maintained out of your reach (it
represents the calling task for that purpose).

In a second stage the implementation of `select()` then suspends the
caller until any of the events become true. (See `fs/select.c`.)

Comment: I see, your explanation and example helped a lot to me and thank you! So it looks like it goes through the functions, (system call sys_ppoll) -> do_sys_poll -> do_pol l-> do_polfd ->(f_op->poll) . I found in do_sys_poll, there is poll_initwait(..) and there the qproc function is initialized to __pollwait function. and__pollwait function seems to put the process in the wait queue. ah, linux system is too complex :)